# Getting error default template arguments may not be used in function templates

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class with default template argument. I am getting "*default template arguments may not be used in function templates*" error for the definition of `MyClass<T, n>::empty()` while compiling this code. I am compiling code on gcc version 4.2.4 (ubuntu 10):

```
template<typename T, int n=10>
class MyClass{
    T Val[n];
    int Capacity;
    int Size;
    public:
    MyClass():Capacity(n), Size(0) {}

    bool empty();
};

template<typename T, int n=10>
bool MyClass<T, n>::empty() {
    return Size?false:true;
}
```

Comment: That's a nicely obfuscated way of writing `Size == 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the question is how to make the code compile, you can remove the default value from the template parameter list of the `empty()` implementation:

```
template<typename T, int n>
bool MyClass<T, n>::empty() {
  return Size ? false : true;
}
```

Note that the implementation must be accessible to code that needs to call `empty()` in a `MyClass<T>` instance. It cannot be compiled in an implementation file.